# Pass command line arguments as string in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to execute [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage) from a Lua script.

It works fine when I pass literals as arguments.

```
os.execute('"C:\\Sox\\sox.exe" -S C:\\SoX\\test.wav -r 22050 C:\\Sox\\SoX_out.wav')
```

or

```
os.execute [["C:\\Sox\\sox.exe" -S C:\\SoX\\test.wav -r 22050 C:\\Sox\\SoX_out.wav]]
```

however, what I'd like to do (as example), when I try this:

```
filename = "C:\\SoX\\test.wav"
os.execute('"C:\\Sox\\sox.exe" -S filename -r 22050 C:\\Sox\\SoX_out.wav')
```

I get:

> C:\Sox\sox.exe FAIL formats: can't open input file `filename': No such file or directory

So my question is how to pass a string properly as command argument ?

Comment: If your file names can contain spaces, more quotes are required: `os.execute([[""C:\Sox\sox.exe" -S "]]..filename..[[" -r 22050 "]]..filename2..[[""]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lua, a string literal is exactly and *only* that string. Strings don't know anything about variables, the global environment, local variables, etc. They're just strings. The string `"filename"` in Lua will always be a string of 8 characters. It will not go out and try to find a variable named `filename` and extract something from it.

What you want is to *build* a string, from multiple strings. Part of the string will come from literals, and part will come from a variable. Lua has several tools for that. The simplest is the `..` concatenation operator:

```
[["C:\Sox\sox.exe" -S ]] .. filename .. [[ -r 22050 C:\Sox\SoX_out.wav]]
```

This builds a new string from a string literal, the contents of the `filename` variable, and another string literal. The spaces you see at the end of the first literal and the beginning of the second are necessary, since Lua will not insert spaces between the two concatenated pieces.

For more complex cases, it's useful to just build a table of parameters and use `table.concat` to build a string out of them:

```
local params =
{
  [[C:\Sox\sox.exe]],
  "-S",
  filename,
  "-r 22050",
  [[C:\Sox\SoX_out.wav]]
}

os.execute(table.concat(params, " "))
```

Note the lack of spaces in the string literals. This is because `table.concat`'s second parameter is a string to be inserted *between* the entries in the array. So between each array element will be a space; we don't need to manually add them.

Comment: Using a table is a nice solution I was unaware of, thanks. But your first suggestion doesn't work for me. When I do ``os.execute[["C:\Sox\sox.exe" -S ]] .. filename .. [[ -r 22050 C:\Sox\SoX_out.wav]] `` I get "unexpected symbol near '..' Why ? This version works fine though: ``os.execute('"C:\\Sox\\sox.exe" -S ' .. filename .. ' -r 22050 C:\\Sox\\SoX_out.wav')``

Comment: @nofish: It doesn't work because you didn't put parenthesis around the argument to `os.execute` in the first one. You did in the version that works.